# Python Databricks cannot visualise dtreeviz decision tree

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, dtreeviz

I need to visualize a decision tree in dtreeviz in Databricks.
The code seems to be working fine.
However, instead of showing the decision tree it throws the following:

> Out[23]: <dtreeviz.trees.DTreeViz at 0x7f5b27a91160>

Running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing, tree
from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz

Things = {'Feature01': [3,4,5,0], 
          'Feature02': [4,5,6,0], 
          'Feature03': [1,2,3,8], 
          'Target01': ['Red','Blue','Teal','Red']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Things,
                  columns= ['Feature01', 'Feature02', 
                            'Feature02', 'Target01']) 

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(df.Target01)
df['target'] = label_encoder.transform(df.Target01)

classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(df.iloc[:,:3], df.target)

dtreeviz(classifier,
         df.iloc[:,:3],
         df.target,
         target_name='toy',
         feature_names=df.columns[0:3],
         class_names=list(label_encoder.classes_)
         )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look into `dtreeviz` documentation you'll see that `dtreeviz` method just creates an object, and then you need to use function like `.view()` to show it. On Databricks, `view` won't work, but you can use `.svg()` method to generate output as SVG, and then use [displayHTML function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#displayhtml-function) to show it. Following code:

```py
viz = dtreeviz(classifier,
  ...)
displayHTML(viz.svg())
```

will give you desired output:

[image]

P.S. You need to have the `dot` command-line tool to generate output. It could be installed by executing in a cell of the notebook:

```
%sh apt-get install -y graphviz
```